# applying tablesorter to multiple tables [Solved]

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, tablesorter

I can't figure out, why it isn't applying to both tables. From what my coworker told me, it might be caused by the html architecture. Which looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <table id="fixed-columns-table">
                    <thead>
                        <th width='10%'><b>LS-Nummer</b></th>
                        <th width='10%'><b>Kunde</b></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table id="fixed-columns-table2">
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The data is stored in variables... And the way those are implemented is a bit complex. That will not be an issue though as my boss already checked that and it worked fine for the past few years.

At the moment, I'm trying to use tablesorter like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id1 = ['#fixed-columns-table'];
    applyTablesorter(id1);
    var id2 = ['#fixed-columns-table2'];
    applyTablesort(id2);
});
```

I tried to change up the architecture and the way of calling the functions, but that didn't work.

This Question might be pretty easy but I am using tablesorter for the first time...

function code:

```
function applyTablesorter(tableIds) {
$(function () {
var startFixedColumns = 0;

tableIds.forEach(function(tableId) {
    $(tableId).tablesorter({
        theme: uid,
        showProcessing: true,
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
        //dateformat : "mmddyyyy",
        dateformat: "yyyymmdd",
        widgets: ['uitheme', 'zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders', 'scroller'],
        widgetOptions: {
            scroller_upAfterSort: true,
            scroller_jumpToHeader: true,

            scroller_height: 300,
            scroller_fixedColumns: startFixedColumns,
            scroller_addFixedOverlay: false,
            scroller_rowHighlight: 'hover',
            scroller_barWidth: null,

            // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
            stickyHeaders_attachTo: '.wrapper_Table' // or $('.wrapper')
        }
    })
});

// use jQuery UI slider to change the fixed column size
$('#slider').slider({
    value: startFixedColumns,
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        // page indicator
        $('.fixed-columns').text(ui.value);
        // method to update the fixed column size
        $('#fixed-columns-table').trigger('setFixedColumnSize', ui.value);
    }
});

// update column value display
$('.fixed-columns').text(startFixedColumns);
});
}
```

Btw, applyTablesort is a different function...

Comment: @JaromandaX Half of the csipt is written in PHP, I didn't think of the fact, that there was none in this problem. Sorry about that. I'll change it.

Comment: You're using `applyTablesorter` for one table and `applyTablesort` for the other - do those two different functions do the same? And _what_ do they do?

Comment: @brombeer I tried to do it with a second function wich I just named applyTablesort. I's basically the same code in those functios tho

Comment: so, those functions are something you wrote ... perhaps you *did something wrong™* in them

Comment: _If_ you're using jQuery Tablesorter they have an [Examples](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Examples) page that should help

Comment: @JaromandaX It's not like I didn't think of that... But I can't find anything wrong with them. I didn't want to add too much code to the Question... Should I add of of them?
Edit: Also it wasn't me who wrote the functions.

Comment: @brombeer I'm gonna look into that. But I don't really know anything about it, as I was just given some code by my boss to work with.

Comment: Yes, you should add _all relevant code_. It's great that you try to keep your question to a minimum, but obviously we can't help you if we can't see every part that's involved with your problem.

Comment: @icecub Yeah, I don't have much experience asking Questions here... I'll add it real quick

Comment: Great. Now what could also help a lot is when you try these functions out, open up your browser console (press F12 in your browser) and see if it's returning any errors. If so, they can really help narrow down any problems.

Comment: @icecub I tried that already, thy're working fine...

Comment: Is that `<table>` the only thing you have for those tables? No `<thead>` or data you could sort?

Comment: @brombeer I do have both but that's about 100 lines and I wanted to keep the Question minimal. Do u want me to add those?

Comment: Not all hundred. Just maybe 1 or 2 examples. The documentation states: "tablesorter works on standard HTML tables. You must include THEAD and TBODY tags". If you don't include them in your question, we might assume that's causing your issue

Comment: @icecub I just added it to the Question.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `<tbody>` part

Comment: I have it in the code, but everythinginside is in php and I don't know anything about the variables and all that. So I don't know if that would be very useful. I'll add the tbody tags tho

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/7thm8w14/ Had to remove the slider part as it was irrelevant to the problem and remove the `uid` for the theme as I lacked the data for that variable. My guess is that the HTML structure output from your PHP is incorrect.

Comment: @icecub That's a good tip, but the ting is, that I'm basically just suppost to make the theme apply for all tables. I know I didn't write that in the function, but I thought I could generalise it since it is in the tablesorter function.
Also I don't think the php is incorrect, since it works with one table and both have the same data...

Comment: You can use whatever theme you want. The theme isn't your issue unless its CSS is bad. The link I provided shows your code working functionality wise. Can't fix what isn't broken. You need to find the cause elsewhere, most likely your PHP output or bad CSS

Comment: Yeah, my boss said he had the same problem some time ago and the problem was the html structure... But I changed it up as much as I could without breaking it. So I honestly don't know that Icould still try. I have been stuck with this problem for 3 or 4 days now... Still thank you for your time.

Comment: If you have a mic, you can always add me on Discord. My name there is the same as here. Just icecub, no numbers or anything. You can share your screen or something so we can have a look at it together.

Comment: @icecub The problem with that is, that I can't really do that in the office. If you have time for this, I might be able to do so at around 17:30. I think we are in the same time zone, since i don't live that far away from you. (You = NL)

Comment: That would be diner time for me, but I'm usually online during / after, so sure. Just add me when you can and I'll DM you when I'm there. Make sure you can access the code from home though. Not much use trying to fix something we can't access because it's at work

Comment: I honestly don't know if I can access the code from home... It's possible that I have to be in the companys intranet. But that might not be an issue since as far as I'm conscerned, this is all local. I will try to acces it from my mobile hotspot. Then we'll know

Comment: As long as you can run it locally, all good. Shouldn't mess around with live code anyway. Or just toss all project related files on some USB drive. Just make sure you don't take any sensitive data with you.

Comment: It's not loading the table in a diffrent network. But I think if we add hardcoded data to it, then we would maybe be able to make it work. I'll add you on discord. Don't be surprised by my voice or my skills tho... I'm pretty young.

Comment: @icecub I can't install Discord on my work laptop. So I'll have to wait untilI get home. I'll copy the needed files on a usb stick.

Comment: It'll be fine. We'll talk later

Comment: @icecub Yes, won't be bad if it doesn't work.

Comment: @icecub Before I forget. I narrowed the problem down to the function not beeing applied to the second table.

Comment: @icecub Sorry, I forgot to tell you that we figued it out. It took a lot of time, but I managed to get it done while I was still at work. Still tank you for your time and help!

Comment: @brombeer I actually don't know... I just continued to do some random stuff as I did the previous 3 days and something worked.

Comment: Next time make sure to inform me. I'm telling other people I don't have time because I promised to help you out. It's fine that you no longer need it, but just letting me wait for you for no reason is not cool.

Comment: @icecub I'm sorry. I tried to reach you on stack as I wasn't home and couldn't add you on discord. I'll try to inform you earlier next time

Comment: It's fine. Glad you got it sorted. Good luck with the project!

Comment: @icecub Thanks! Been a while since I've a nice person on here... Have a nice day!